# Passing pointer on vector's elements into map

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector, stdmap

The following function must find a sportsman in the vector allSportsmen by his full name and birthdate and then find some sport by its name and add this sportsman and this sport from vectors to map participants where key is the sportsman and the values are sports he does

```
 vector<Sportsman> allSportsmen;
 vector<Sport> allSports;
 map<Sportsman, vector<Sport>> participants;
 void addSportToSportsman(string fullName, string birthDate, string sportName) {
    Sportsman* s;
    Sport* sport;
    for (auto x = allSportsmen.begin(); x != allSportsmen.end(); x++) {
        if (x->getFullName() == fullName && x->getBirthDate() == birthDate)
        {
            for (auto y = allSports.begin(); y != allSports.end(); y++) {
                if (y->getSportName() == sportName)
                {
                    s = allSportsmen.at(x);
                    sport = allSports.at(y);
                    participants[s].push_back(sport);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At lines:

```
s = allSportsmen.at(x);
sport = allSports.at(y);
```

I have error:

> C++ no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list argument types are: (std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_Simple_types, std::_Vec_iter_types<Sportsman, size_t, ptrdiff_t, Sportsman *, const Sportsman *, Sportsman &, const Sportsman &>>>>) object type is: std::vector<Sportsman, std::allocator>

And the same for Sport

And then:

> Compiler Error C2679
> binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iteratorstd::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

How do I fix this and normally pass this sportsman and sport stored in their vectors? Btw, should this map receive pointers like  `map<Sportsman*, vector<Sport>*> participants;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want pointers, you'd have to take the address of your dereferenced iterators

```
s = &(*x);
sport = &(*y);
```

I would warn you, however, that this is a fragile design if you mutate your vectors `allSportsmen` or `allSports` (e.g. `push_back`, `emplace_back`, `resize`, etc) that causes a reallocation, you'll likely invalidate your pointers.

Also note that you'd have to change the type of your map to store pointers

```
map<Sportsman*, vector<Sport*>> participants;
```

Comment: The proposed change is also very fragile. As the vector grows, pointers to its elements will be invalidated. So the keys and values of the map will invalidate. And the keys do not compare by value, so it will be impossible to find a key by value, you need the object with the exact same address. Edit : I'm not sure if this was meant to be implied by the answer, but it wasn't apparent for me.

Answer (score 1):

With these as input ...

```
vector<Sportsman> allSportsmen;
vector<Sport> allSports;
map<Sportsman, vector<Sport>> participants;
```

... I'd rework it slightly:

- Drop `allSportsmen` since the *keys* in the map would provide the same list.
- Make `allSports` a `set<Sport>`. They are supposed to be unique, and also, a pointer to an element in a `vector` can get invalidated if the `vector` data is moved due to deletion of elements or when adding new elements.
- Store iterators, not pointers, in the `map`s *value* `vector`.

So, this would be my approach:

```
std::set<Sport> allSports;
std::map<Sportsman, std::vector<std::set<Sport>::iterator>> participants;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oWqdj7)

If each `Sportsman` is supposed to map to a unique set of sports, you could possibly consider changing the *value* `vector` to a `set`, making it

```
std::map<Sportsman, std::set<std::set<Sport>::iterator>> participants;
```

If the order isn't important you could use the `unordered` counterparts instead.

Comment: A lot of the time, a `map` of `vector`s can instead be a `multimap`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You are perhaps correct. I must admit I haven't used `multimap`s much. :) A nice thing with a plain `map` in this case is that it provides a  unique list of `Sportsman` which makes it easy to drop one container.

Comment: `s = allSportsmen.at(x);`: You are sending an iterator `x` to a function that wants an integer.  Even if that operation were correct, it would return a `Sportsman` object which you try to assign to a `Sportsman *` variable.  The following `sport = allSports.at(y);` has similar errors.  Cory Kramer's corrections and criticism seem good.

Comment: @TWBennet You miss a good part of what I'm suggesting. I'm _not_ sending an iterator `x` to an integer expecting function (or - I've done a boo-boo). Read all my suggestions again and you'll hopefully find that the return values are pretty accurate when it comes to the limited info gotten from OP. I just read what OP presented and I can't see the purpose of it in any other way then I initially did. - In fact - I'm more than confident in my suggestion.

Comment: @TWBennet Just to be clear "_You are sending an iterator x to a function that wants an integer._" is not what I'm suggesting at all.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear.  My only purpose was to make some explanation to the original questioner about what his compiler errors mean.  Folks have made some fine suggestions for improvements, but didn't seem to address that matter.

Comment: @TWBennet Make an edit to my answer and I'll review it. If I find it brings some clarity I''ll approve and credit you.  An alternative: If your answer is fundametally different than mine, add an answer. If I like it, I'll upvote it.